# Can’t figure out Samba file share permissions as needed.

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, samba

I’m in the final project class for my degree and my group has to have a Linux server that supports a Windows environment. With the files in the file share need to be read only, can be edited and then saved as a new file. I'm also the server guy in my group and the other members are Cisco networking. I'm a new to coding things for Samba.

I have an Ubuntu Linux file share running with Samba. Users should be able to see and make files. The files need to be read only. A user should be able open a read only file, edit it as needed and then save it as a new file like a read only file in Windows. With the file share users can see the contents and drag files into it. But they can’t open “Template.doc” from the share to edit and then save as a new file with the changed contents.  The error I’m getting is “You don’t have permissions to modify files in this network location. Contact your administrator.”

This is the code in the smb.conf file for the share itself in the file system is 777.

```
    [Share]
    path = /share/Share
    writeable = yes
    ;browseable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    create mask = 0444
    directory mask = 0777
```

What do I need to add to the smb.conf file to get the share working as needed? For testing at the moment it's just in a generic workgroup with my laptop from not having enough RAM to virtualize the Windows servers and test client. No authentication or crazy domain things will me implemented with this.

Thank you for your time! :D

Comment: Sounds like a file permission issue.  Have you check the Samba logs?